# Class declaration error at explicit keyword

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting an error: 'in' has not been declared. In my class in Qt.
It is on the constructor line that starts with explicit.

```
class InputForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InputForm(int ibot, in itop, double dbot, double dtop);
    void displayForm();

public slots:
    void computeResult();
private:
    void setupForm();
    int m_BotI, m_TopI;
    double m_BotD, m_TopD, m_Pay;
    QLineEdit* m_StrEntry;
    QLineEdit* m_IntEntry;
    QLineEdit* m_DoubleEntry;
    QLabel* m_Result;
    QString m_Name;
    static QRegExp s_NameFormat;
};
```

Comment: Presumably it should be `int itop`

Comment: By the way, you don't need `explicit` there at all.

Comment: Explicit is only for one-argument constructors to prohibit implicit type conversion (like when you have `MyClass::MyClass(int)` if you then write `int i; MyClass obj = i;` it will be converted to `MyClass obj = MyClass(i)` if no `explicit` keyword supplied)

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: Since 2011, `explicit` is also for arbitrary constructors to prohibit implicit conversion from an initialiser list. So here it would prevent `InputForm form = {0,0,0,0};`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
InputForm(int ibot, int itop, double dbot, double dtop);
                  /*  ^  */
```

Typo. `int itop`, not `in itop`. <sup><sub>(Did you really read the error message and tried anything yourself?)</sub></sup>

Note that you might need to change the type in your implementation file if you copied the line. Also note that `explicit` isn't necessary, as this constructor cannot be used for any implicit conversion anyway.

Comment: whoops, didn't notice that, guess that's what happens when you stay up all night coding, you make silly mistakes, thanks.

Comment: @user2291259: Have a walk, take some fresh air. If it's to late for that, you're probably better off sleeping anyway.

Comment: Might as well remove the `explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

> 'in' has not been declared

```
explicit InputForm(int ibot, in itop, double dbot, double dtop);
//                           ^^^
```

Compiler doesn't know what `in` means as it's not a keyword nor any user defined symbol(if you haven't done that). If you agree it's typo of `int`,

```
explicit InputForm(int ibot, int itop, double dbot, double dtop);
//                           ^^^
```

Or you could define a type for `in`, for example:

```
struct in
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:-

```
explicit InputForm(int ibot, in itop, double dbot, double dtop);
```

to

```
explicit InputForm(int ibot, int itop, double dbot, double dtop);
```